How to enable http-pipelining for aiohttp.ClientSession?
I set limit of tcp connections to 1, because server allows no more than one connection per client. Also I use keep-alive connections. I configured client session like this:
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
connector = aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit=1)
session = aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=loop, connector=connector)

I would like to send requests asynchronously even with this client configuration. So I should use http-pipelining, right? But I could not find information in aiohttp docs how to enable it. Also I see from server logs that requests were sent one after another. Can anyone help me to enable http-pipelining, please?
